# How do I store permanent data

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, plist

I am new to iOS development and have the following problem.

EXPLANATION:
I have an app which consists of several mini games. Each mini game is available through in app purchase. However the mini game availability is saved in a BOOL variable like this:

```
 _miniGamesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
 NSMutableDictionary *mutDictMg0 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:3];
 [mutDictMg0 setValue:[self.gameAvailabilityMutableArray objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"GameAvailable"];
[_miniGamesArray addObject:mutDictMg0];
```

PROBLEM:

Each time I start the app the game availability is checked from the `self.gameAvailabilityMutableArray` which is set to:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)gameAvailabilityMutableArray
{
    if (!_gameAvailabilityMutableArray)
    {
        //[_gameAvailabilityMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:@[@1,@0,@0,@0    ,@0,@0,@0,@0]];
        _gameAvailabilityMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:@[@1,@1,@1,@1    ,@1,@1,@1,@1]];


    }
    return _gameAvailabilityMutableArray;
}
```

When the customer buys a mini game I want the array to be set to (example):

```
 @[@1,@1,@0,@0    ,@0,@0,@0,@0]]
```

TRIED SOLUTIONS:
I tried to implement the array by calling the iTunes server and writing the data. However, the time to recieve the request is greater then the app loading time. The second problem arrises if there is no internet connection, then the app crashes.

I also tried using .plist files. I don't know why but writing to the plist file doesn't change it's contest all the time! Some times it works , sometimes it doesn't... Sometimes the app loads the values correctly sometimes it mixes them with the last values.

QUESTION:

Is there a way to store permanent app data which is being checked when the app loads beside plists?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I would store this in core data. NSUSerDefault values can be changed by manually by the user so they could unlock mini games without purchasing.

Comment: Is data stored via core data going to stay saved after app restart/device restart? I have not used core data so far so I dont know anything about it.

Comment: Yes, core data is a persistent store coordinator. See: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Devpedia-CoreData/persistentStoreCoordinator.html

Comment: how did you write the `.plist` file? have you archived and unarchived it properly?

Comment: @CW0007007, the `CoreData` is still can be updated manually outside of the code (e.g. with any SQLite database editor), I'd recommend to use the keychain to store such info.

Comment: Well anything is 'hackable' but it's certainly not something your average consumer is going to be able to do ...

Comment: @holex - For the plist files I used the following code:  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; I used a helper class. I will try core data, if I get it working I will post the code/solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  save your data in NSUserDefaults.then use below conditions for app start first time or handle another conditions.

 BOOL iSFirstTime = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"AppStartFirstTime"];
    if (!iSFirstTime) {
        NSLog(@"Application start first time");
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"ImgDownloaded" forKey:@"ProductIDDef"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"AppStartFirstTime"];
    }else{
        //   NSLog(@"we are here");
        if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"ProductIDDef"] isEqualToString:@"ImgDownloaded"]) {
            NSLog(@"All transaction and Image Downloading has been perform successfully");
        }else{
//If any network problem or any thing else then handle here.
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I would try this , but since @CW0007007 said "NSUSerDefault values can be changed by manually by the user so they could unlock mini games without purchasing." I am not sure if the user could easily unlock the mini games. Is it this unsafe?

Comment: if you want to more security then used the data encryption technology.NSUserDefault is a dictionary.that reside on your app.so,my opinion it can't easily accessible.

Comment: if you make ipa then how can you access the dictionary value of app?

Comment: In the end this was the fastest and best solution. It works like a charm. I tried with core data but had lots of problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the data in NSUserDefaults using the following code:

```
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_gameAvailabilityMutableArray forKey:@"gameArray"];
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronise];
```

and you can retrieve the array using

_gameAvailabilityMutableArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"gameArray"];

Comment: I would try this , but since @CW0007007 said "NSUSerDefault values can be changed by manually by the user so they could unlock mini games without purchasing." I am not sure if the user could easily unlock the mini games. Is it this unsafe?

Comment: I think, an end-user will not be able to unlock, but user with a Jailbroken iDevice could do so.

Comment: This helped a lot in setting and saving. Ty. Works great.